# Validating Login Form, I'm using NSString?

Tags: ios, objective-c, authentication, nsstring

*EDIT* See BELOW for FINAL CODE!

The problem I have is that my Response String is incredibly long from the server. All I want to do is capture the "OK" message from the string.  Which then lets me know that you have authenticated to the server. I'm guessing "isEqualToStirng" is the wrong way of going about this. So I'm looking for an alternative. :) This is my code! Thanks!

Here is a sample of the string from the server: 
2014-01-14 13:02:34.297 AppTest[84788:70b] RESULT : {"result":"ok","userId":5,"appList":[{"appId":89,"appame":"plastic stranger facelifting ","userName":"Oblong","startDate":"2014-02-15T16:12:43","totView":1502,"totLike"‌​:2681,"totComment":3884},{"appId":101,"appName":"quiet donkey fling

```
NSURLResponse *response = nil;

NSData *dataURL = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];


NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:dataURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"RESULT : %@", responseString);


 if ([responseString isEqualToString:@"OK"])

{

    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard=[UIStoryboard

                                  storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];

    Home *mainView=[mainStoryboard

                     instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"mainView"];

    mainView.modalTransitionStyle=UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;

    [self presentViewController:mainView animated:YES completion:nil];



}else{}
```

WORKING CODE:

```
 NSError *e = nil;
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dataURL options:0 error:&e];

NSString *result = json[@"result"];
if ([result isEqualToString:@"ok"])

{

    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard=[UIStoryboard

                                  storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];

    Home *mainView=[mainStoryboard

                     instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"mainView"];

    mainView.modalTransitionStyle=UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;

    [self presentViewController:mainView animated:YES completion:nil];



}else

{}
```

Comment: Could you post an example of the complete string response that you are getting from the server?

Comment: This is a small snippet 
2014-01-14 13:02:34.297 AppTest[84788:70b] RESULT : {"result":"ok","userId":5,"appList":[{"appId":89,"appame":"plastic stranger facelifting ","userName":"Oblong","startDate":"2014-02-15T16:12:43","totView":1502,"totLike":2681,"totComment":3884},{"appId":101,"appName":"quiet donkey fling

Comment: Don't put that in a comment. Update your question with the result so people can read it.

Comment: Include the full response in your question.

Comment: ok its up there. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your response shows that what you're receiving from the server is a JSON dictionary. So you'll want to do something like this:

```
NSError *e = nil;
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dataURL options:0 error:&e];

NSString *result = json[@"result"];
```

Comment: How can I add the if statement then? This won't work
      
 if ([result boolValue]) {

Comment: I had the code example wrong. I edited it, so you can see that `result` is a string, so you check to see if that equals `@"ok"`. Based on your response that you posted, the "ok" is lowercase.